# download file from web source, selectively

Tags: 12.10, bash, downloads, wget

If anyone has heard of Bukkit, you know that their files are usually of three types: Development, Beta, and Realease. Click ([here](http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit)) for examples. I need a script that:

- Loops through the directory
- Gets the latest *Stable* version (probably just as simple as looking at the version number as they have a simple naming convention, each stable version is succeeded by -Rx.0, while developmental and beta versions are succeeded by -Rx.x)

After that I know I'll need to use `wget` to download the file.

Note: If your just going to post code, at least tell me what it does so I can use it later if I need to

Answer (score 1):

The script's main task is to figure out which of those links it should `wget`. Parsing web pages is really complicated. I wouldn't recommend `bash` for it!

Python is easy to write in comparison and has a robust HTML parsing library called [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Once you've "souped" the link, downloading it is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure this out, but here it is ;)

-c , in case you want to stop and start from where you left it

-r -A "*-R[0-9].0*" , gets only files that have in the middle -Rx.0 and x belonging to {0,1,...9}

-np , means no parent directories (goes with the -r option)

-nd , stands for no directory

-e robots=off , turn off robots

So in your case you would do something like

```
wget -c -e robots=off -r -np -nd -A "*-R[0-9].0*" http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/
```

I can't get it from the site you posted, but I think it somehow redirects things here.